# Can I use pace instead of data-table's processing?

Tags: jquery, datatable, pace

I'd like to use [PACE](http://github.hubspot.com/pace/docs/welcome/) for [Datatable](https://datatables.net/)'s ajax requests. So , I disabled the datatable's processing as `processing : false`. And then what do I need to work [PACE](http://github.hubspot.com/pace/docs/welcome/)'s processing bar for showing every [Datatable](https://datatables.net/)'s ajax requests ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like it should just work by default for AJAX requests, if you're wanting it to apply for sorting/processing events you might need something like the following:

Adapted from https://datatables.net/reference/event/processing 
You'll probably want to trigger PACE on the datatable processing event by the sounds of things:

```
$('#dataTable')
    .on( 'processing.dt', function ( e, settings, processing ) {
        if(processing){
            Pace.start();
        } else {
            Pace.stop();
        }
    })
.dataTable();
```

Comment: You could also use the preXhr and xhr events if it doesn't work automatically on AJAX - https://datatables.net/reference/event/preXhr, and https://datatables.net/reference/event/preXhr for the documentation on those particular events. It should be fairly trivial to adapt the above examples to those particular events (on `preXhr.dt` and on 'on `xhr.dt`) would be the two events that need hooking

Comment: In my application, I have many pages using datatable with different **id**s. Can I make the setting for globally instead of modifying existing codes as your answer ?

Comment: It is work as you described. Am I still need to set `ajax` option of **pace** to `false` ?

Comment: I'd suggest applying a class to them that you can then use globally ie `$('.pace-dt').on...` If you manually trigger `Pace.start` and `Pace.stop` via event handlers you may need to set it false if you want to prevent other AJAX requests triggering Pace. If applying a class doesn't work with the above try something like `$('.pace-dt').each(function(){ $(this).on....  })`

Comment: Gotta stress that I'd expect that PACE should be able to automatically detect the AJAX requests and manually triggering shouldn't be required unless using it for something like a sort that might take some time on the client side.

Answer (score 1):

Well if you want to show the `PACE` for every ajax request in your application then you can specify it like below

Adding the pace options before loading it.

```
    <script>
        window.paceOptions = {
            ajax: {
                trackMethods: ['GET', 'POST', 'PUT', 'DELETE', 'REMOVE']
            }
        };

    </script>
    <script src="../js/progressBar/pace.min.js"></script>
```

This will show up your PACE progress bar for every ajax request to your server.

Comment: Yes you right .. I had also read about this from [PACE Documentation](http://github.hubspot.com/pace/) but I think it is not effect on DataTable's ajax request. But I am not sure cos I'm running on localhost and request are too fast.

Comment: In my case it works perfectly fine when loading the `DataTables` (through `DataTables` ajax request).  Can you create a `JSFiddle` of your problem ?

Comment: In my case it works on first-time page loading. I would like to get this on triggering [dataTable search](https://datatables.net/reference/api/search()) also.

Comment: You are doing server side processing or client side? If its server side then it will work, If client side then it will not.

Answer (score 1):

Is simple use this form:

```
$('#dataTable').on('processing.dt', function(e, settings, processing) {
    if (processing) {
      Pace.stop();
      Pace.bar.render();
    } else {
      Pace.stop();
    }
  }).DataTable();
```